# Railsでpersisted? が true のオブジェクトの値が保存されていない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで`Company`モデルがあり、`has_many` `QuarterValue`という関係を持っています。

そして`Company`のインスタンスメゾットで`QuarterValue`の特定の値を一括で変更するという処理をしているのですが、何故か変更がDBに反映されません。

変更後に

```
company.quarter_values.map(&:persisted?)
```

を試すと全て`true`が返ってきます。
また`company.quarter_values.last`で該当カラムを確認すると値が変更されているのですが

```
quarter_value = QuarterValue.find(company.quarter_values.last.id)
```

で確認すると該当カラムの値は変更されていません。

該当のカラムの型は`decimal`で代入しようとしてる値は`BigDecimal`です。

```
quarter_value.update(column_name: value)
```

で値を更新すると問題なく行われます。

一体何が問題なのでしょうか？
何か基本的な事を見落としてる気がするのですが、
どう調べれば良いかもわからない状態で困っています。

Rails: 4.2.1 でDBは `Postgresql` を使っています。

Comment: 変更しているSQLは予想通り（意図通り）のモノがは発行されていますか？

Comment: もう少し全体のソースを見たい気もしますが、当てずっぽうだと reload を試されては如何でしょうか? company.reload.quarter_values とか company.quarter_values.reload などなど。(外していたらスミマセン)

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi それらしい部分は意図通りのSQLになっているのですが、発生する条件の切り出しがまだうまくいっていないので、他の所で何か変なことをしてしまっているのかもしれません。

Comment: @naopontan 問題の処理の後に `company.quarter_values.reload` すると`QuarterValue`の数が約半分に減りました。意図しないコピーが生成されてしまっているようです。具体的な原因はまだわかりませんが、これで問題解決の糸口が掴めそうです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@naopontan さんのアドバイスで`reload`を使った所、必要ないインスタンスが生成されていたのでそれを止めて、それから

```
quarter_values.find_each { |q| q.update(foo: nil) }
```

という処理をしてる部分があったので、

```
quarter_values.update_all(foo: nil)
```

に変えた所、期待通りの処理になりました。

なお

```
quarter_values.each{|q| q.update(foo: nil)}
```

でも問題は発生しませんでした。